# Why can't I add sumproduct formula?

Tags: excel-formula, phpexcel

I tried to add a column named FTE containing this formula :

```
=I2/SUMPRODUCT(I:I,(M:M=M2) * (C:C=C2) * (N:N=N2))
```

This formula worked when applied in Excel, but when added from php, I just get an error:

> maximum execution time calculation.php phpexcel

```
$assembly = $arrayWorksheet->addColValByRow($assembly, 'FTE', ['= I', '/SUMPRODUCT(I:I,(M:M=M', ')*(C:C=C', ')*(N:N=N'], '))');
// Output : =I2/SUMPRODUCT(I:I,(M:M=M2)*(C:C=C2)*(N:N=N2))
```

Sadly I can't figure out why. My initial formula was `SUMIFS` that I converted into `SUMPRODUCT`, because I know that `SUMIFS` isn't implemented yet.

```
function addColValByRow($worksheet, $title, $valArray, $finalVal = NULL) {
        // Take the last column
        $lastCol = key( array_slice( $worksheet[1], -1, 1, TRUE ) );
        $newCol = ++$lastCol;
        // tke the last cell
        $lastCell = key( array_slice( $worksheet, -1, 1, TRUE ) );
        $worksheet[1][$newCol] = $title;

        for ($i = 2; $i <= $lastCell; $i++) {
            $worksheet[$i][$newCol] = "";
            foreach (array_keys($valArray) as $key) {
                $worksheet[$i][$newCol] .= $valArray[$key] . $i;
            }
            if ($finalVal != NULL) {
                $worksheet[$i][$newCol] .= $finalVal;
            }
        }

        return $worksheet;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `SUMPRODUCT()` that's causing the problem, it's the fact that PHPExcel doesn't support column/row ranges fully, so it's a column range like `I:I` or `M:M` or `C:C` that's causing the problem.

If you can change this to an actual cell range (e.g. `I1:I2048`), then it shouldn't be an issue.

And (for future reference) `SUMIFS()` is implemented in the latest code in the `develop` branch on github

Comment: I've tried 
`=I2/SUMPRODUCT(I2:I1306,(M2:M1306=M2)*(C2:C1306=C2)*(N2:N1306=N2))`
It Works on Excel, but maximum execution time is still exceeded.
Do I need to extend execution time limit ?

Comment: If it's taking a long time to execute, then yes..... executing formulas takes time, and while limiting the range by using cell references rather than column references will reduce that time it won't eliminate the need to do that calculation on 1305 rows of data

Comment: Unless you need these calculations to be performed in PHP, then you might be better suppressing calculation if all you're doing is writing this data to a spreadsheet file

Comment: Well, the "maximum time exceeded" error was my mistake, I changed the way i'm downloading the sheet and it's all good. So I didn't have to extend execution time limit. Thanks for everything.